# OBJ - FBX - From Z brush - Always crashing on import

Tags: zbrush

I found out Maya LT cant export high res mesh's so got to find a new way to scale my sculpts for retopo, sadly right out of the gate every type of map from OBJ, to FBX. BIN just sends Blender unresponsive, gave it 20 minutes to see if it was just a loading error but nope.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, is it crashing or is it hanging for a really long time ? The imports / exports in blender are using the python API so they can be quite inefficent for very large files, exponentially so

Comment: Its going unresponsive on anything over 2GB then eventually crashes. 

Manged to get a 1.5gb file in after awhile, but its super laggy? Im very lost haha

Comment: Might be you run out of RAM, check your task manager while you are importing to see if you don't hit the limit

Comment: Seems too sit around 63 - 67% with everything else closed, the smaller file i dont have much issues moving it till i want to CTRL+Z or change between objects, scaling working fine. Any chance them operations are tied to something else?